# Java list's .remove method works only for second last object inside for each loop

Tags: java, foreach

I am seeing a weird behavior.

```
    List<String> li = new ArrayList<>();
    li.add("a");
    li.add("b");
    li.add("c");
    li.add("d");
    li.add("e");
    for(String str:li){
        if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("d")){
            li.remove(str);     //removing second last in list works fine
        }
    }
```

But if i try to remove any other than second last in the list, i get ConcurrentModificationException. It came to my attention while reading "Oracle Certified Associate Java SE 7 Programmer Study Guide 2012" which incorrectly assumes that .remove() always works with an example of removing the second last in the list.

Comment: actually i know how to remove an element in array, but i wanted to point out why it works only on the second last element, is this a bug as non-consistent behavior ??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In a list, adding or removing is considered as a modification. In your case you have made
5 modifications(additions).

‘for each’ loop works as follows,

> ```
> 1.It gets the iterator.
> 2.Checks for hasNext().
> ```

```
public boolean hasNext() 
{
      return cursor != size(); // cursor is zero initially.
}
```

> 3.If true, gets the next element using next().

```
public E next() 
{
        checkForComodification();
        try {
        E next = get(cursor);
        lastRet = cursor++;
        return next;
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        checkForComodification();
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
}

final void checkForComodification() 
{
    // Initially modCount = expectedModCount (our case 5)
        if (modCount != expectedModCount)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
}
```

Repeats steps 2 and 3 till hasNext() returns false.

In case if we remove an element from the list , it’s size gets reduced and modCount is increased.

If we remove an element while iterating, modCount != expectedModCount get satisfied 
and ConcurrentModificationException is thrown.

But removal of second last object is weird. Lets see how it works in your case.

Initially,

> cursor = 0 size = 5 --> hasNext() succeeds and next() also succeeds
>   without exception.
>   cursor = 1 size = 5 --> hasNext() succeeds and next() also succeeds
>   without exception.
>   cursor = 2 size = 5 --> hasNext() succeeds and next() also succeeds
>   without exception.
>   cursor = 3 size = 5 --> hasNext() succeeds and next() also succeeds
>   without exception.

In your case as you remove ‘d’ , size gets reduced to 4.

> cursor = 4 size = 4 --> hasNext() does not succeed and next() is
>   skipped.

In other cases, ConcurrentModificationException will be thrown as modCount != expectedModCount.

In this case, this check does not take place.

If you try to print your element while iterating, only four entries will be printed. Last element is skipped.

Hope I made clear.

Answer (score 5):

Don's use `List#remove(Object)` here since you are accessing elements from the List in for-each loop.

Instead use [Iterator#remove()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) to remove an item from List:

```
for(Iterator<String> it=li.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    String str = it.next();
    if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("d")) {
        it.remove();     //removing second last in list works fine
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use `Iterator#remove()` method while removing elements from a `List` while looping . Internally the `for-each` loop will use the `Iterator` to loop through the `List`and since the behavior of an `Iterator` is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling Iterator's remove() method.You are getting the exception .

This loop :

```
for(String str:li){
    if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("d")){
       li.remove(str);     //removing second last in list works fine
     }
}
```

is basically

```
Iterator<String> itr = li.iterator();
  while(itr.hasNext()){
    String str = (String)itr.next();
    if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("d")){
        li.remove(str);     //removing second last in list works fine
    }
}
```

***Why removing second last element doesn't throw exception ?***

Because by removing the second last element you have reduced the size to the number of elements which you have iterated over. A basic `hasNext()` implementation is

```
    public boolean hasNext() {
       return cursor != size;
    }
```

So in this case the `cursor=size=4`, so `hasNext()` evaluates to `false` and the loop breaks early before the concurrent modification check is performed in `next()`. The last element is never accessed in this case . You can check that by adding a simple OR condition in the `if`

```
    if(str.equalsIgnoreCase("d") || str.equalsIgnoreCase("e")){
        // last element "e" won't be removed as it is not accessed
        li.remove(str);   
    }
```

But if you remove any other element `next()` is called which throws the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Answer (score 2):

ConcurrentException is raised because of the fail fast behaviour of the ArrayList. This means you can not modify the list while iterating it except Iterator#remove() .

Refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to iterate over an `ArrayList` and remove elements then you should do it this way:

```
for(int index = yourArrayList.size() - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
    if(yourCondition) {
        yourArrayList.remove(index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate "backwards" and remove elements, but not forward. So instead of iterating from the first element to the last, iterate from the last to the first.

Pseudo-code:

```
for(int i = list.size() -1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   list.remove(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to remove all then.**removeAll** should do the trick **rather than iterating through the collection**. I think it is speedier too.